# Is there a way to run git in read-only mode?

Tags: git, readonly

I'm writing a script to run things like `git status` in each of the subdirectories of the current directory, so I can quickly get information about several git repos. However, I want to prevent any commands that modify the repos. I wouldn't want to commit ten repos at once. I can't just use a whitelist of git subcommands, because I might want to run `git branch -a` to see the branches in each repo, but not `git branch new-branch-name` to create a new branch in each repo.

So is there a way to run git so that it will abort instead of making anymodifications to the repo, but work fine when running read-only commands?

Edit: What I want to do is make a git-subdirs command that works like this: When I type `git subdirs COMMAND ARGS`, I want to do something like `for dir in */; do cd $dir && git COMMAND ARGS && cd ..; done` (only with additional error checking). Except that if `git COMMAND ARGS` would modify the repo in any way, I don't want to do it, because it's exceedingly unlikely that I would want to make the same change to many different repos.

Comment: Would you want to prevent fetching? I can see that being a very common use case for a script like this, and you may think of it as not modifying the repo, but it definitely does.

Comment: Well, I could still implement a whitelist for commands like fetch or push that modify non-destructively, but it would be nice to start with a baseline implementation that doesn't have the capacity to accidentally break 10 repos with a single mistyped command.

Comment: Actually, push can be destructive if you use `-f`, so it's like your `git branch` example.

Comment: @MatrixFrog: Push (assuming it's to a real remote) doesn't do anything to the *local* repository, `-f` or not.

Comment: Oh right! Good point. But it seems likely that if you want to avoid changes to the local repo you may also want to avoid changes to a remote repo. I guess it depends what you're trying to do...

Comment: Actually, push *does* modify the local repository, in order to keep track of where the remote refs are. But I think it does this after performing the actual pushing, so pushing from a read-only repo would not fail until after modifying the remote repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented this using unionfs-fuse. This is completely non-portable, but it works for me on Ubuntu. Try it out with `git subdirs status` in the directory that contains all your git repos.

You can get it from Github: https://github.com/DarwinAwardWinner/git-custom-commands

Answer (score 4):

It's a little kludgy, but you could simply run your script as a user who doesn't have write permissions on the repository. To keep from having to enter a password, you could use an ssh keypair and ssh into your own machine as that user. (or maybe configure it through sudoers?)

Unlike a whitelist, this is guaranteed not to have any accidental holes or overzealous restrictions. It doesn't require actually modifying the permissions of the repo, just the permissions of the user acting on it. And it doesn't take any extra setup like git-daemon would.

(I suppose I should note that there's no built-in "read-only" option to pass to git. It simply tries to do things, and if it has permission to, does them.)

Comment: +1 This is the first thing I thought of before I read any of the answers, and I think it's the easiest and least risky way. The fuse solution is interesting, but seems like overkill.

Answer (score 1):

Why not deny write access to the repository directory?

```
$ chmod -R -w repo.git
```

Comment: The problem here is that the repos should normally be writeable, just not for the purposes of this script. This operation would also be really hard to reverse - some of the contents of a repository are always write-protected for safety, so you couldn't do `chmod -R +w` to undo it.

Comment: Thank you for commenting for me. That's exactly the problem with this solution.

Comment: On the other hand, I could use unionfs-fuse to make a read-only view of my repos.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can indeed use a whitelist of commands. Eg. instead of git-status use git-diff-files and git-branch you could use git-show-ref or git-for-each-ref. Make sure to check out the low-level (plumbing) commands. Likely you will find a simple focused low level command for all your scripting needs.

Comment: The sentiment about plumbing commands is a good one, but sometimes it is nice to have some of the porcelain ones too. I think a whitelist might get pretty tedious to maintain, but depending on use cases it could be worth a shot.